# How to get "receiver" socket object in socket.io /lib/client.js file on v > 1.4.0?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I had built interception calls in the socket.io file located under `node_modules/socket.io/lib/client.js` with version 1.3.7 (at least I think so, however I have to update to 1.4.5 because of other requirements). These changes allowed spoof information coming from the sender socket and they were done before continuing to send the data to the receiver socket.

Before (around 1.3.7), the method ran before sending a packet was the following:

```
Client.prototype.packet = function(packet, preEncoded, volatile){
 var self = this;
 var sockets = this.sockets[0];  //this helds the socket object
```

but now (1.4.5) socket.io changed its call to the following

```
 Client.prototype.packet = function(packet, opts){
 var sockets = this.sockets[0];  //gives undefined
```

I tried to look throughout the given objects but couldn't find the sockets of the receiver user.

Back in 1.3.7 I was able to effortlessly give properties to a socket object (e.g: socket.some-property = 1; in the .js file ran by nodejs in the root of the server) and later be able to get this `some-property` back in node_modules/client.js whenever the receiver got some packet so I could intercept the call but now it does not work and I would like to apply my old code to this new context in order for it all to function again.

Comment: Create your own socket object.

Comment: @TheMatrixISReal what is that even supposed to mean, you do understand how socket.io works right? I can't simply create a socket object if it does not work in the whole context and does not go through the supposed calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
var socketObject = {};
io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
    socketObject[client.id] = {socket: client};
    client.on('data', function (somedata) {  
        socketObject[client.id].data = someData; 
    });    
    client.on('disconnect', function() {
        delete socketObject[client.id];
    });
});
```

Comment: That would require me to completely change the whole work I have done already, which would be a lot. There certainly has to be a way to intercept the packet in the new version and change it accordingly with access to the socket object. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: Furthermore, this doesn't even answer the question. I can't intercept packets received by the socket using your code.